# how to zip a directory with its files using Terminal on Mac

Tags: terminal, zip

i am trying to zip a folder with files in terminal using

`zip -r myzipfile.zip myDir`

but this doesn't include the files 
What should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can just use *; there is no need for *.*. File extensions are not special on Unix. * matches zero or more characters—including a dot. So it matches foo.png, because that's zero or more characters (seven, to be exact).
>
> Note that * by default doesn't match files beginning with a dot (neither does *.*). This is often what you want. If not, in bash, if you shopt -s dotglob it will (but will still exclude . and ..). Other shells have different ways (or none at all) of including dotfiles.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57014

Answer (score 3):

You can use two commands: zip or ditto.

Using the zip command:

```bsh
zip -r myzipfile.zip myDir/
```

or using the ditto command:

```bsh
ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent myDir myzipfile.zip
```

Source: https://www.polynique.com/operating-systems/how-to-zip-files-and-folders-in-macos-from-terminal/